# Cypress testcase: Select only text of an element (not the text of its children/descendants)

Tags: html, cypress, testcase

HTML Code:

```
<p class="target">
    <span>I am Span 1 of target_value 1*</span>
    <span>I am Span 2 of target_value 2*</span>
    target_value   /* I want to get this value in cypress test case */
</p>
```

Note*: Both the texts "I am Span 1 of target_value 1" and "I am Span 2 of target_value 2" are dynamic and can change at times.But these spans might contain the text "target_value".
In cypress test case how can I select the text "target_value" in

directly(not in its children) and check if it is rendering or not. I just want to get the main text value which is not inside any of its children element.

Comment: SO what I understood, is you want to select only the span which has the target_value ?

Comment: So, I want to select the last "target_value" in my question excluding the two spans (which may have "target_value" as a text). which is text directly written inside of a element("target_value" inside <p> tag in my question) but not inside any of its children(span in my question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you target is a text node. There are 3, but the first two are just spacing chars between spans.

```js
cy.get('p')
  .then($el => $el[0].childNodes)  
  .then(children => [...children].filter(child => {
    return child.nodeType === 3   // ignore <span>s
      && child.textContent.trim() !== ''  // remove spacing between <span>s
  }))
  .then(textNodes => textNodes[0].textContent.trim())  
  .should('eq', 'target_value   /* I want to get this value in cypress test case */')
```

---

If the target text is always last within `<p>`

```js
cy.get('p')
  .then($p => $p[0].lastChild.nodeValue.trim())   
  .should('eq', 'target_value   /* I want to get this value in cypress test case */')
```

---

Excluding children with `.not(children())`

```js
cy.get('p')
  .then($p => $p.contents().not(Cypress.$('p').children()).text().trim())
  .should('eq', 'target_value   /* I want to get this value in cypress test case */')
```

---

Clone and remove children

```js
cy.get('p')
  .then($p => $p.clone().children().remove().end().text().trim())
  .should('eq', 'target_value   /* I want to get this value in cypress test case */')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. You extract everything and split the string and get the last value and assert or perform any actions.

```js
cy.get('p.target').invoke('text').then((text) => {
  expect(text.split('\n')[3].trim()).to.equal('some value')
})
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, But I want to filter the "target_value" which is in "target" class and not inside any of its children span.(the last "target_value" text in my question)

Comment: Its checking in full text of  the <p> tag ("I am Span 1 of target_value 1 I am Span 2 of target_value 2 target_value") not just the direct outside text of <p> tag (which is only "target_value")

Comment: Ok, let me try that locally.

Comment: Basically the ".not('span')" is checking that the <p> with target class name should not be a <span> (which will be always true), Thank you